# python recipe: list item nearest equal to value

Tags: python

Considering a list like `[0,3,7,10,12,15,19,21]`, I want to get the nearest minimum digit closest to any value, so if I pass `4`, I would get `3`, and if I pass `18`, I would get `15`, etc.

Comment: Will the list always be sorted? When you say *"nearest minimum"* do you just mean the largest number smaller than the input, or does the delta actually matter?

Comment: What if the value is equal to the entry in the list? Should we go to the next biggest or return the equal number?

Comment: Based on his example, I would say that we don't know for sure if it is sorted (possibly not since his answer works without sorting). I would also say that based on his answer, he's looking for equal matches.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [bisect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) which isn't too difficult. It's used for binary searching like this. This does assume a sorted list.

```
from bisect import bisect_right

def find_le(a, x):
    'Find rightmost value less than or equal to x'
    i = bisect_right(a, x)
    if i:
        return a[i-1]
    raise ValueError

mylist = [0,3,7,10,12,15,19,21]
print find_le(mylist,4)
print find_le(mylist,-1)
print find_le(mylist,29)
print find_le(mylist,12)
```

Running interactive:

```
>>> print find_le(mylist,4)
3
>>> print find_le(mylist,-1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in find_le
ValueError
>>> print find_le(mylist,29)
21
>>> print find_le(mylist,12)
12
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple options here.

The simplest would be to iterate over the array and stop when a) you've reached the end of the array OR b) the value at the current position is larger than the one you're looking for. Then simply return the last value found. (One edge case to consider: what happens if the number requested is smaller than ALL values of the array?)

This solution assumes that the array is ordered. If not, it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

If your list is small, iterating through it is the best bet. You'll avoid some overhead, plus there's no point in over-engineering this task. If you want your code to be a bit more "correct", or if you want this to scale well on larger inputs, I'd recommend a binary search approach. This is, of course, assuming that your input is guaranteed to be sorted. If unsorted, you have no choice other than to iterate through the values while keeping track of a delta. Here's a relatively high-level explanation of the binary search strategy:

1. Do a binary search
2. If equal to the value you were searching for, return the value at the previous index.
3. If less than the value, return that index.
4. If greater than the value, return the previous index.

It might help to run through a few examples to prove to yourself that this will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `yield` and `next()` to avoid iterating the whole list

**Online Demo - https://repl.it/C9YJ/1**

```
values = [0,3,7,10,12,15,19,21]

def get_closest(value, items):

    previews_item = None
    for item in items:
        if item >= value:
            yield previews_item

        previews_item = max(item, previews_item) if previews_item else item

    yield None


print next(get_closest(4, values))
# 3

print next(get_closest(18, values))
# 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Really messy and probably inefficient solution but it works

```
test=[0,3,7,10,12,15,19,21]
value=25
nearest=[]
for i in test:
    if i == value:
        nearest.append(test[(test.index(i))])
        break
    if i>value:
        nearest.append(test[(test.index(i))-1])
        break
if len(nearest) == 0:
    nearest.append(test[-1])

print nearest[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [0,3,7,10,12,15,19,21]
val = 18

x.sort()
close =  [abs(_ - val) for _ in x]
ans = (x[close.index(min(close))])
if ans > val:
    ans = (x[close.index(min(close)) -1])
print (ans)
```

Comments:

(1.) We cannnot assume that the original is pre-sorted as it was not specified as such. Hence, I did an in-place sort. If the order of the list items need to be preserved, then make a copy of the list and then sort.

(2.) There are some excellent posts using the bisect module, and using iterators. I wanted to show another way by demonstrating list comprehensions, and the use of a throw-away variable (the underscore).

(3.) If the list is long, you should use bisect. If the list is short (specified to be no more than a few hundred), don't over-engineer the code; linear search is fine. Just remember in software, you are always juggling between, time vs. space, readability, maintainability, etc.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, Ajean! I shall comment on my own code and hopefully I can add some value.

Answer (score 0):

using bisect. 
one problem: code will give last element once checking number is smaller than first element in list

```
import bisect
lst = [0, 3, 7, 10, 12, 15, 19, 21]
lst[bisect.bisect_left(lst,-1) - 1]
```

Answer (score -2):

Well, `a` is the list and `b` the value:

```
max(a for a in a if a <= b)
```

More efficient way? Probably not?

Comment: It certainly doesn't give the right answer.

Comment: @marcusshep that makes no difference

Comment: max rather than min of course, fixed it.

Comment: You mean... `max(v for v in a if v <= b)` but this is a linear search.