# python recipe: grouped by sum of tuples

Tags: python

A list of tuples `a` like `('foo',1),('bar',2),('foo',2),('bar',3)`, I want each unique key or `a[0]` along with a sum of each value or `a[1]`, so: `{'foo': 3, 'bar': 5}` -- some quick way of doing this w/o `itertools`?

Comment: 1. Quick compared to what? 2. Why not itertools?

Comment: Next time you find yourself writing [python recipe:](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38233057/3001761), cook something yourself first. And note http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/248731

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick without itertools...

```
pairs = [('foo',1),('bar',2),('foo',2),('bar',3)]

def sum_pairs(pairs):
  sums = {}
  for pair in pairs:
    sums.setdefault(pair[0], 0)
    sums[pair[0]] += pair[1]
  return sums.items()

print sum_pairs(pairs)
```